# PHP preg_match not working as HTML5 pattern

Tags: php, regex, html

I have a function to validate prices. 
The input correct

```
150.22
150,25
```

html5:

```
<input type='text' pattern='[1-9]+([,.][0-9]{1,2})?'/> // Works
```

But then I validate the same input in php with preg_match().

```
public function price($price){
    $pattern = '[1-9]+([,.][0-9]{1,2})?';
    return preg_match($pattern, $price);
}
```

And this always returns me `false`, which means is incorrect.

You can test my regex here: http://regexpal.com/

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP you need to use [regex delimiters](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) also.

Try this:

```
$pattern = '/[1-9]+([,.][0-9]{1,2})?/';
```

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I'll accept your answer in 10 mins. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked out. Please accept the answer whenever you can.